# Map size() > 0 but begin() == end()

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm writing a class that stores data in a `std::map`. After adding some pairs to the map with my `add()` method, I try to `std::cout` those pairs. However, the loop I wrote to do this "breaks" as soon as it tries to access the first element in the first pair of the map.

```cpp
class Database {
private:
  std::map<std::string, std::string> data;
public:
  void add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value) {
    data.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
  } 
  void display() const {
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
      std::cout << it->first << "|\t" << it->second << std::endl; 
    }
  }
  // Other methods
};
```

If I `cout` `data.size()`, I can see that the map is not empty—in my tests, I'm getting a size of 3. Likewise, I can see that `data.empty()` evaluates to `false`. However, when I print the addresses of `data.begin()` and `data.end()`, they are identical, and to me that implies that the map actually *is* empty. I suspect the problem has something to do with that—the loop is trying to get `it->first` but it can't because it seems the map is empty (...even though it's not?).

What am I missing? (I'm really new to writing questions on StackOverflow... please let me know if I need to give more information.)

Comment: You print the address of `data.end()`? Why on earth would you do that? Anyway, create a [mcve] please.

Comment: Your code is part of a class.  That class needs to be instantiated correctly for any of that code to be valid.  You need to post a [mcve] showing where, when, and how you instantiated the `Database` instance.  For example, I can easily break all of your code doing something like: `Database *db; db->add("abc", "123"); db->display();`

Answer (score 2):

Taking the class above, and using it in an MCVE...

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Database {
private:
  std::map<std::string, std::string> data;
public:
  void add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value) {
    data.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
  } 
  void display() const {
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
      std::cout << it->first << "|\t" << it->second << std::endl; 
    }
  }
  // Other methods
};

int main()
{
    Database d;

    d.add("Hello", "World");
    d.add("Foo", "Bar");
    d.add("Bing", "Bong");

    d.display();
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
Bing|   Bong
Foo|    Bar
Hello|  World
```

Which seems to be working as expected.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77b6a699ad3485a5